# Do Javascript regexes contain an implicit ^?

Tags: javascript, regex

I think the result should be the same ("0") in both examples, but it isn't. Why?

```
"0 Y".match(/[0-9]*/) // returns "0"

"Y 0".match(/[0-9]*/) // returns ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't an implicit `^`. However, an empty string at the beginning do match the regex `/[0-9]*/`, so `""` is returned.

You may view the matching process (without the `/g` flag) like this:

```
for (cursor in [0, 1, .. string.length-1])
  if (the regex matches string.substr(cursor) with an implicit '^')
     return the match;
return null;
```

```
"0 Y" -> find longest match for [0-9]* from the current cursor index (beginning)
      -> found "0" with * = {1}
      -> succeed, return.

"Y 0" -> find longest match for [0-9]* from the current cursor index (beginning)
      -> found "" with * = {0}
      -> succeed, return.
```

You should therefore avoid regexes that matches an empty string. If you need a digit to be matched for sure, use `+`.

```
"0 Y".match(/\d+/)
```

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't have an implicit `^`.

`*` Means match zero or more characters, since there are zero digits at the beginning of the string, it matches, and returns an empty string.

Comment: Then why it doesn't match "the empty string" in the beginning of "0 Y" and instead continues until it finds the 0?

Comment: Because it's greedy, and matches as much as it can, from the first position it can.

Comment: @AndreKR - The empty string is after the `0`, it matches it first, again try `"0 Y".match(/[0-9]*/g)` to see this.

Comment: @AndreKR, because it isn't looking for an empty string, it is looking for zero or more digits at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I see, so "the empty string" is the non-matching "Y" which is empty because it's not matching.

Comment: +1 for this one as the comments made me understand the problem and I accepted KennyTM's because it's more elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're after is:

```
"0 Y".match(/[0-9]/) // returns "0"

"Y 0".match(/[0-9]/) // returns "0"
```

Your current `*` version matches 0 *or more* numbers...so an empty string is a match.  Try this as an example, to get a clearer view:

```
"Y 0".match(/[0-9]*/g) // matches: "", "0", ""
```